# Executing javascript code to accept terms and open next page

Tags: javascript, jquery, lua, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I would like to crawl a javacode rendered website that requires clicking on an 'Accept Terms' button to enter.  I am using Scrapy and Splash and have tried to execute the javascript code using the both splash endpoints 'render.html' and 'execute'.  In both cases the the output is the start page. Why dosent this work as expected?

url = start page with the "Accept Terms" button.

url/index.aspx = page I want to render.

Using render.html:

```
yield scrapy.Request('url', self.parse, meta={ 'splash':
{   'endpoint':'render.html','args': {'js_source':
'document.getElementById("AcceptTerms").click();', 'html': 1, 'wait':
0.5}}})
```

or by using execute and lua:

```
lua_source_string = 'function main(splash)
splash:go("url/index.aspx")
splash:wait(0.5)
splash:runjs("document.getElementById(\'AcceptTerms\').click();")
return splash:html() end'

yield scrapy.Request('url', self.parse, meta={ 'splash': { 'endpoint':'execute','args': {'lua_source' : lua_source_string}}})
```

'url' is the page that is rendered.

If I follow the example from http://blog.scrapinghub.com/2015/03/02/handling-javascript-in-scrapy-with-splash/ and use the following lua string with jquery like so:

```
lua_source_string = 'function main(splash)
splash:autoload("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js")
splash:go("url/index.aspx")
splash:wait(0.5)
splash:runjs("$(\'#AcceptTerms\').click();")
return splash:html() end'
```

Or using the jquery code like so:

```
lua_source_string = 'function main(splash)
splash:autoload("i/am/restricted/to/only/two/links/see/above/jquery.min.js")
splash:go("url/index.aspx")
splash:wait(0.5)
splash:runjs("$(\'#AcceptTerms\').trigger(\'click\');")
return splash:html() end'
```

I get the same results.  The rendered page is 'url'.

Comment: I think it depends on the page, maybe you should share it.

Comment: The urls are: `http://foreclosuresearch.arapahoegov.com/foreclosure` and `http://foreclosuresearch.arapahoegov.com/foreclosure/index.aspx`

Comment: @dave Why does it depend on the page?

Comment: I didn't make that comment, I only edited the question for code formatting. Sorry I don't know anything about lua.

Comment: @eLRuLL Why does it depend on the page?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I suggest to use this workaround:

```
function setup_casperjs(splash)  
  -- preload CasperJS client utils.  
  -- __utils__ object is compatible with CasperJS  
  splash:autoload("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/n1k0/casperjs/master/modules/clientutils.js")  
  splash:autoload([[    
    window.__utils__ = new ClientUtils({});  
  ]])
end

function main(splash)  
  setup_casperjs(splash)  
  assert(splash:go(splash.args.url))  
  assert(splash:runjs("__utils__.click('#AcceptTerms')"))  
  splash:wait(0.5)  
  return splash:html()
end
```

See https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash/issues/200#issuecomment-112552839 for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Using the recommended method of sending a lua script to the execute endpoint,

1. splash:go should load the start page at url, where this script will be executed, not the destination at url/index.aspx
2. since splash:go loads the page, it is unnecessary to splash:wait immediately afterwards
3. however, it is necessary to splash:wait following splash:runjs
4. verify the id of the button by inspecting the html source.

So you could pass the id of the button to be clicked within splash.args to

`function main(splash)
    splash:go(splash.args.url)
    splash:runjs('document.getElementById["'.. splash.args.submit ..'"].click();')
    splash:wait(0.5)
    return splash:html()
end`